# Can I add Kotlin extension function to Java class?

Tags: kotlin, extension-methods

I'm trying to create extension function like this:

```
fun UHFTAGInfo.toReadUhfTagInfo(): ReadUhfTagInfo {
    return ReadUhfTagInfo(this.epc, this.count, this.rssi.toIntOrNull())
}
```

It is supposed to convert `UHFTAGInfo` (from java library) to `ReadUhfTagInfo` (my class in Kotlin).

I'm trying to use it like this:

```
UHFTAGInfo i = getUHFTAGInfo();
ReadUhfTagInfo ri = i.toReadUhfTagInfo();
```

At this moment my `toReadUhfTagInfo` function is at top level, but finally I want to put it in my ReadUhfTagInfo class, like this:

```
class ReadUhfTagInfo(var epc: String, var cnt: Int, var rssi: Int?)
{
    fun UHFTAGInfo.toReadUhfTagInfo(): ReadUhfTagInfo {
        return ReadUhfTagInfo(this.epc, this.count, this.rssi.toIntOrNull())
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you import this extension? Normally, IDE will do this for you if you use autocompletion, etc. If you write your code entirely by hand, you need to still add an import or let IDE fix it for you.

Comment: IDE didn't imported it (I'm using Android Studio that usually does it). I have tried to add id manually, but autocomplete can't see it.

Comment: Maybe the problem is in the fact, that `UHFTAGInfo` class is Java, not Kotlin? Adding Kotlin extension to Java class looks weird... I will change my post title.

Comment: We can add extensions to Java classes, no problem, but I didn't notice you try to use this extension from Java code, correct? This is not possible, extensions are a feature of Kotlin, Java doesn't support extensions and can't use them like this. From Java perspective extensions are just static utility methods..

Comment: You can call Kotlin extension functions from Java, sure, but you can't call them with extension function syntax, you must call them like static methods.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Now I understand. Thank you! How about posting answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call Kotlin extension functions from Java, sure, but you can't call them with extension function syntax, you must call them like static methods.  If you, for example, define

```
// file: Foo.kt

fun Bar.baz() { ... }
```

then in Java, you would call this as

```
FooKt.baz(bar);
```

Comment: Correct with minor remark -- extension methods are not always 'static'. They are instance methods of declaring class (not receiver class) if declared within a class declaration.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want to have `toReadUhfTagInfo` as a member function on the `ReadUhfTagInfo` class. That would imply that, in order to convert a `UHFTAGInfo` to a `ReadUhfTagInfo`, you already need a `ReadUhfTagInfo` object (which will presumably go unused except to serve as the receiver object.

Extension functions defined inside a class are [member extensions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html#declaring-extensions-as-members) and essentially have two receivers.

> You can declare extensions for one class inside another class. Inside such an extension, there are multiple implicit receivers - objects whose members can be accessed without a qualifier. An instance of a class in which the extension is declared is called a *dispatch receiver*, and an instance of the receiver type of the extension method is called an *extension receiver*.

If you want the extension method to act like a static method in Java (i.e. not require an instance of the enclosing class to execute), then you do the same thing we do with all static methods in Kotlin: We put it in a companion object.

```
class ReadUhfTagInfo(var epc: String, var cnt: Int, var rssi: Int?)
{
  companion object {
    fun UHFTAGInfo.toReadUhfTagInfo(): ReadUhfTagInfo {
      return ReadUhfTagInfo(this.epc, this.count, this.rssi.toIntOrNull())
    }
  }
}
```

As pointed out in the comments, this will still require the name to be imported into the current scope (as all extension methods do), but it won't require a receiver of type `ReadUhfTagInfo` to call anymore.

Comment: Well, it didn't worked as well (extension for Java class in a Kotlin companion object of another class). I just created secondary `ReadUhfTagInfo` constructor that takes `UHFTAGInfo` as parameter:  `constructor(info: UHFTAGInfo) : this(info.epc, info.count, info.rssi.toIntOrNull())`. I think that extension was not necessary. Thank you for very informative answer.